# stumped by dynamic button text update

Tags: jquery, button, mobile, dynamic, text

I been trying to figure this out all day and can;t figure it out. My code works perfectly on jsfiddle but does not in my local environment.

I made sure that versions of jQuery and CSS are the same.

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/date.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="p_home" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="controlgroup">
 <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" id="prev">prev</a>
 <a href="" data-role="button"  id="today"></a>
 <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" id="next">next</a>
   </div>

  </div>
 <script>
// show date
showDate(0);

// set up prev day
$("#prev").click(function (e) {
showDate(-1);
 });

// set up next day
$("#next").click(function (e) {
showDate(+1);
 });

function showDate(ddiff) 
{
var tday;
if (ddiff === 0)
{
   tday = Date.today().toString('MMMM d, yyyy');
}
else 
{
   var cur=$("#today").text();
   tday = Date.parseExact(cur, 'MMMM d, yyyy').addDays(ddiff).toString('MMMM d, yyyy');
}
    $("#today .ui-btn-text").text(tday);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rados/Ee9nq/30/)

My problem is that in my local environment, the showDate(0) does not work when I do $("#today .ui-btn-text").text(tday) but if I use $("#today").text(tday) it updates the date just fine.

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

That might be issue with how jQuery selects.

Try this instead

```
$(".ui-btn-text", "#today").text(tday);
```

Updated fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Ee9nq/33/

Comment: I tried that but that did not work in my env. This one is driving me nuts. As you can see, the exact code works fine on fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your script code into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
});
```

It should resolve it.